# Delete an array element from a document with Mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I am having a schema called **ReferralHistory**.
It contains  set of users and array of referred users.

**ReferralHistory**

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var refferalHistorySchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    user: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'User',
        unique: true
    },

    referrals: [{
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'User'
    }],
});
var ReferralHistoryModel = mongoose.model('ReferralHistory', refferalHistorySchema);
module.exports = {
    referralHistory: ReferralHistoryModel
}
```

I need to delete a  particular user from referrals array  in the collection ReferralHistory[Here i only know id of referred user].How can i achieve this?

**Edit**

**Collection**
[image]

I tried

```
db.referralhistories.update({ "u_referrals": "593281ef966d7f0eeb94db3d" }, { "$pull": { "u_referrals": "593281ef966d7f0eeb94db3d" } });
```

**O/P**[image]

But document is not updating.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You use the [`$pull`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/pull/) operator with [`.update()`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.update). So assuming `referredId` as the value you know

```js
ReferralHistoryModel.update(
  { "referrals": referredId },
  { "$pull": { "referrals": referredId } },
  { "multi": true },
  function(err,status) {

  }
)
```

Noting the `{ "multi": true }` means the update can be applied to more than one matched document in the collection. If you really only intend to match and update one document then you don't include that option since updating only the first match is the default.

If you want to be more specific and also have the "user" to match, then you can do:

```js
ReferralHistoryModel.update(
  { "user": userId, "referrals": referredId },
  { "$pull": { "referrals": referredId } },
  { "multi": true },
  function(err,status) {

  }
)
```

And then the match needs both values to be present as opposed to **any** `ReferralhistoryModel` documents which matched the `referredId` you supplied.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.I have tried your solution.But not getting the result.Updated the question

Comment: @Muhsin because you are entering that in the shell/robomongo/whatever. The values are `ObjectId` and not strings. In the shell you need to use `ObjectId("593281ef966d7f0eeb94db3d")` in order to match. Mongoose however will cast the type for you.

Comment: It got working now.Thank you so much for your help. This is so very helpful to me.